# Django 1.8 Not Serving Static Files in Development

Tags: django

I am using the exact settings as in https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/static-files/ and my app is not loading the files. I've spent way to long trying to solve something so trivial but it's just not working. I've looked at alternatives, but these didn't work either.

This is in my setting file:

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static")
```

This is at the end my urls file:

```
] + static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
```

I did a collect static when I had the static file dirs so there should be the correct files in my static dir. I also created test files and nothing.

Heres what it will say in the debug view:

```
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://localhost:8000/static/assets/stylesheets/style.css
Raised by:      django.views.static.serve
```

Last time I wrote an app this worked fine, i'm not sure why is isn't now.

Comment: What's your directory structure?

Comment: The stylesheets directory is at: myApp/static/assets/stylesheets

Comment: Have you set up `STATICFILES_DIRS`?

Comment: Well I was going to have it to the same as `STATIC_ROOT` but it gave me an error. What should it be?

Comment: Hey @Callum, is this resolved?

Answer (score 1):

You haven't used the exact settings in the docs...Which is fine, but you need to at least do the following, if `DEBUG = False`:

1. Set up `STATICFILES_DIRS`. This should be the absolute path to the folder where your static assets live (before they're "collected").
2. Set up `STATIC_ROOT`. This is different than the above path, and is where all of your static assets will be collected when you run `collectstatic`.
3. Run the `collectstatic` command to collect (i.e. copy) your assets from your `STATICFILES_DIRS` to your `STATIC_ROOT`

Depending on your configuration, and if `DEBUG = True`, you don't even need to define `STATIC_ROOT` in development mode.

Comment: When Django collects static, does it store the file path or something? I just did that and it worked. I did run collect static before but it only got the admin files because I didn't have any other assets

Comment: Nope! It simply collects all of your static assets (which may be in multiple directories) to the same root directory.